# Can a loading sweet alert wait for a loop to finish before closing?

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, async-await, sweetalert

I want to display a loading sweet alert while a loop is running. How can I make that possible. What currently happens is the sweet alert only opens for a split second after the loop has finished. I have tried making testFunc async and awaiting the wait function, but that didn't help. Not sure what to do at this point. I appreciate any help. Thank you so much

```js
function wait(ms) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  var end = start;
  while (end < start + ms) {
    end = new Date().getTime();
  }
}
function testFunc() {
  sweetAlert({
    title: "Please wait",
    showCancelButton: false,
    showConfirmButton: false,
  });

  wait(3000);
  console.log("done");
  sweetAlert.close();
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.0/sweetalert.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.0/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<button id="testBtn" onclick="testFunc()">TEST</button>
```

Link to fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/n4w8pf7L/22/

Comment: Please do not include links to other sites in your question.  If those sites or the content on them disappears, your question becomes useless to the reader.

Comment: @Tibrogargan what SO rule says links aren't allowed in questions?

Comment: @reformed there's no rule, but there is this: [ask]

Comment: @Tibrogargan yes people are encouraged to provide a JSFiddle, but not without providing the code as well. He did both. What's the problem?

Comment: Quote: "Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time. Use Stack Snippets to make a live demo of inline JavaScript / HTML / CSS."  It's just as easy to do a snippet, and they provide mechanisms to copy the code directly into an answer.  more value in it.  Fiddles are nice, but yeah - they can disappear.

Comment: Re-added the fiddle, since it may be helpful for others trying to answer this. The stack snippet is for future visitors. Off-site links are certainly allowed when accompanied by a working, minimal example of the question/problem. Link **only** questions are off-topic.

Answer (score 4):

Your `wait` function is blocking the main thread, that's not really wait for anything.
You need to handle this asynchronously with `Promises` and `async await`.

```js
function wait(ms = 0) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
}

async function testFunc() {
  sweetAlert({
    title: "Please wait",
    showCancelButton: false,
    showConfirmButton: false
  })

  await wait(3000);

  console.log("done");
  sweetAlert.close();
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.0/sweetalert.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.0/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<button id="testBtn" onclick="testFunc()">TEST</button>
```

Comment: ... You too ...

Comment: Would be super awesome if you could do this so that an event was fired when `wait` returned, and there was a listener that closed the alert instead of blocking.

Comment: @Tibrogargan using async await there's no blocking, with it you are literally waiting.
Other scripts can be executed while the async function waits for the Promise of "wait" function.

Comment: The code inside the async function is literally blocked.  Blocking anything with a wait state is never really a good idea.

Comment: @Tibrogargan if what you want is to run other things in the function without worrying about waiting for the "wait" function you can just avoid the "await" and use "then" method.
wait(300).then(() => alert.close())

Comment: You're arguing two sides of the same coin.  Either way you want to do it, either by expressly sending an event or by using `.then()` they are both preferable to blocking.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This worked, but I'm not sure why you cant make this work with the while loop I had in the wait function. The main issue I'm having is having a sweet alert appear before the execution of a loop and close when the loop completes. It always ends up with the sweet alert opening and closing at the completion of the loop. Thanks

Comment: @YakovBorukhov JavaScript is a single threaded language.
If you use a loop that takes too long it will block the main thread.
No code can be executed.
You were waiting in a wrong way.

Comment: @Xion14 So how would you use a promise with a loop? I tried it and the swal again only showed up after the promise returned a value. I thought the swal would be forced to show up first. Is it possible to replace settimeout with a loop?

Answer (score 0):

Using event handling instead of blocking while the alert is shown (blatant derivative of Xion 14's answer :P).  This is provide a workaround to a condition where an alert window cannot be dismissed due to an unexpected error.  While this obviously not an issue with a simple timeout, the OPs intent seems to be that work will be getting done while this alert is displayed.

```js
const waitComplete = new Event('waitComplete')

function wait(ms = 0) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => document.dispatchEvent(waitComplete), ms))
}

async function testFunc() {
  sweetAlert({
    title: "Please wait",
    showCancelButton: false,
    showConfirmButton: false
  })

  wait(3000);
}

document.addEventListener('waitComplete', () => {
  console.log("done");
  sweetAlert.close();
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.0/sweetalert.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.0/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<button id="testBtn" onclick="testFunc()">TEST</button>
```

Comment: I don't see really any benefit in using an event to close the alert.
You are just overcomplicating the code with it.

Comment: The alert can now be closed cleanly from anywhere in the "system", not just from the [unreachable] internals of an async function that could potentially be waiting on a state that will never be reached.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This worked, but I'm not sure why you cant make this work with the while loop I had in the wait function. The main issue I'm having is having a sweet alert appear before the execution of a loop and close when the loop completes. It always ends up with the sweet alert opening and closing at the completion of the loop. Thanks

Comment: JavaScript is single threaded.  That thread is responsible for many things, including keeping the UI responsive.  If you keep that thread [busy waiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) you stop everything else from happening.  This has some pretty severe consequences.  The most noticeable one is the UI locks up.  Where possible, you want to avoid doing this.  The main method is to use asynchronous programming (i.e `async await`), but that has drawbacks too, mainly that it can cause issues synchronizing things - so you get things happening at the wrong time.  Using events can help.